# Coverage reports in Azure DevOps deployment pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure DevOps for configuring CI/CD. I have Selenium UI tests that runs in the **CD** pipeline. I'm planning to get a code coverage report on this test. So far I have the pipeline with the following tasks; 
[image]

As you can see the "Code coverage enabled" option is enabled. How can I view the coverage report? If not at least download it?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're on a release you need to you need to go to the **Test Run** that is produced by your release and view the **Attachments**

### Prerequisite

You'll need to make sure the test task is uploading attachments.
[image]

### Nav from the release:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

### Nav from Test Management

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I see in the console that the coverage reposrt is added to D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\9186d451-d1f2-4a31-8d6f-88b0cb1f12c0\VssAdministrator_fv-az45 2019-02-21 00_37_50.coverage. But the attachments are not available in the test run.

Comment: Do you have the "upload test attachments" option checked on your test task?

Comment: Yes I have. Are your tests Selenium UI tests? I wonder if it's not calculating the coverage of the UI tests.

Comment: Hmm... that might be it. I'm not running selenium tests here. What do you get if you output the contents of that `.coverage` file to the log via powershell?